# Cannot make two objects in same time in Javascript. One object hides another one

Tags: javascript, html, geometry, html5-canvas

I want to create a symbol using javascript. It needs to create circle and rectangle. I created circle and rectangle. But when rectangle make under the circle, then circle not display. How fix this issue?

```js
var circle = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctx = circle.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(300, 300, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();

//create gradient
var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(300, 300, 50, 300, 300, 5);

var fillColor = 'black';
ctx.fillStyle = fillColor;
ctx.fill();

var rect = document.getElementById('canvas2');
var ctx2 = rect.getContext('2d');
ctx2.beginPath();
ctx2.rect(200, 10, 200, 40);
ctx2.stroke();

var grd2 = ctx2.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 100, 100);
grd2.addColorStop(0, "black");
grd2.addColorStop(1, "white");

ctx2.fillStyle = grd2;
ctx2.fill();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas1" width="800" height="250"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas2" width="800" height="300"></canvas>

  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't think the rectangle has anything to do with it. The circle doesn't show even if you remove the rectangle code.

Answer (score 2):

only problem in your code is that your canvas is 250px in height and you are drawing circle outside it at (300,300)

I just changed `arc` call

```
ctx.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
```

```js
var circle = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctx = circle.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI); // changed this line
ctx.stroke();

//create gradient
var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(300, 300, 50, 300, 300, 5);

var fillColor = 'black';
ctx.fillStyle = fillColor;
ctx.fill();

var rect = document.getElementById('canvas2');
var ctx2 = rect.getContext('2d');
ctx2.beginPath();
ctx2.rect(200, 10, 200, 40);
ctx2.stroke();

var grd2 = ctx2.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 100, 100);
grd2.addColorStop(0, "black");
grd2.addColorStop(1, "white");

ctx2.fillStyle = grd2;
ctx2.fill();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas1" width="800" height="250"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas2" width="800" height="300"></canvas>

  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```